# Чем отличается StringBuilder от StringBuffer?

Tags: java

Чем отличается [StringBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) от [StringBuffer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)?

Я что один, что второй, использую для того, чтобы составить строку из заведомо неизвестного количества частей.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`StringBuffer` - это наследие с ранних версий JDK (до 1.5). Отличается тем, что он синхронизирован.

Answer (score 5):

Используйте StringBuilder, когда работаете с одним потоком, StringBuffer когда с многими потоками.